# Does Vm7 in minor key function as dominant?

Tags: chords, chord-theory

I heard Vm7 in minor key could be used insted of V7 but In Cm key doesn't it have to have the natural B note to function as dominant ? But how does it work ? If it does not function as one what's its function ?

Comment: Sometimes it may have dominant function, but due to the chord is a m7 chord, it could not have it as "strong".  It would normally have tonic function.  Also, a Vm7 is **extremely** rare.

Answer (score 11):

In common practice music (that is, music by composers like Bach, Mozart, Beethoven, etc.), the use of minor v7 as a harmony—as opposed to V7—is quite uncommon. When it does occur, it doesn’t usually have dominant function at all.

Probably the most common use of this uncommon harmony is in first inversion as a passing chord between a i and a VI: i – min v6 or v6/5 – VI. The reason for the unraised leading tone in this progression is that it has a smoother bass line without an augmented second. If we were in c minor, the bass line would be C – Bb – Ab instead of C – B – Ab. The vast majority of uses of minor v and v7 arise our of similar circumstances; a melodic need to use the natural version of the seventh scale degree exists, so the minor form of v is needed to harmonize it without a huge clash.

Situations like that account for all of the uses of minor v as a harmony that I’m aware of. It should be noted, however, that minor v as a *key area* is quite common in minor-key pieces. For example, in minor key sonata form works, the most common key for the second half of the exposition is III, but minor v is definitely the next-most common.

It also should be noted that minor v and v7 are perfectly normal and can still have dominant function outside of the major/minor common practice universe. For example, v7 (and bVII) are standard dominant function chords in Mixolydian, Aeolian and Dorian. As a result, there are definitely times you will hear even common practice composers use it as a dominant function chord during modal parts of their music. This is especially common, for example, in Russian Romantic composers like Mussorgsky and Tchaikovsky.

Answer (score 1):

'Function' is a concept that belongs to the sort of harmony that is built on the dominant - tonic relationship.  G7 has a dominant relationship to C.  We can extend that to stringing 'secondary dominants' together - Em7, Am7, Dm7, C. We can colour it with tritone substitutions and the like.  But it's still all basically about dominant - tonic progressions. The 'cycle of 5ths thing.

But there's another world of harmony that, apart from perhaps retaining the idea of a tonic, doesn't really deal with function.   There's no function in Cmaj7, Dm7, Em7...  except a vague (and easily diverted) sense of C as 'home'.   Likewise the progression Ab, Bb, C.  Which could easily continue D, E...

If your ear is attuned to functional harmony, you may be able to hear Gm as the dominant of C.  (It can certainly be a secondary dominant in a 'cycle of 5ths' Gm, C, F progression.)   Or we may have entered a less structured type of harmony where a chord is sufficiently justified by being adjacent to the one before.  Or by sharing some notes with it. Or...   And this isn't 'modern, way-out' stuff.  It happens all the time in popular music.